# How show that this statement is true.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality

Given $V(x)  = -5x_1^2 (x_1^2 - 1) - 4x_1x_2$.
Show that there exist $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ arbitrarily close to $x = 0$ such that $V(x_0) > 0$. 
I have no idea how to prove this. I was thinking to put some small numbers $x_1, x_2$ that satisfies the condition but this is not a formal prove. Can you help me to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that$$V(x,x)=-5x^2(x^2-1)-4x^2=x^2(1-5x^2),$$which is greater than $0$ if $x\in\left(0,\sqrt{\frac15}\right)$.

Comment: I dont get this :(

Comment: *What* is it that you you don't get? Is it the equality $V(x,x)=x^2(1-5x^2)$? Or the fact that this expression is greater than $0$ if $x\in\left(0,\sqrt{\frac15}\right)$?

Comment: did you want to say that, if we're taking $x_1 = x_2 = x$ then we have $V = x^2(1-5x^2) $. Then this function will aways be positive definite for the value of $x \in (0, \sqrt(1/5))$ Do I really need more statement to complete this prove or not, sir?

Comment: Yes, I took $x_1=x_2=x$ and, no, nothing else is needed. This is a complete proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let $0<\epsilon < 1$ and $(x_1, x_2) = (\epsilon, 0)$, then  we have

$$V(x)=-5\epsilon^2(\epsilon^2-1)>0$$

Comment: why can we take the value of $x_2 = 0$?

Comment: we just have to show the existence of such point right? so we can pick any point that satisfy the criteria?

Comment: I know but my lecturer wanted for abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

$V(\frac 1 n , \frac  1 n)=-\frac 5 {n^{4}} +\frac  5 {n^{2}}-\frac 4 {n^{2}} >0$ for all $n \geq 3$. Every neighborhood of the origin contains the points $(\frac 1 n , \frac 1 n)$ for infinitely many values of $n$. Hence we can take $x_0=(\frac 1 n , \frac 1 n)$ with $n$ large.

Comment: can you provide more statement sir? I really need help

Comment: @SutMar I have added some details.